# What is the best syntax for using a `where` statement to find association counts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I can think of a few ways to do this, but I'm unsure what to choose..

I have the class `Topic` and I am trying to scope this so that I only return Topics if it has the associated object `Reply` or `topic.replies` as a count greater than 0.

Worst way to do this :

```
@topics.select{ | topic | topic.replies > 0 && topic.title == "Conversation" }
```

Ideally, I'd like to use a `where` scope.

```
  scope = current_user.topics
  scope = scope.joins 'left outer join users on topics.registration_id = registration_members.registration_id'
  # scope = .. here I want to exclude any of these topics that have both the title "Conversations" and replies that are not greater than 0
```

I need to "append" these selections to anything else already selected. So my selection shouldn't exclude all others to just this selection. It's just saying that any `Topic` with replies less than one and also called "Conversation" should be excluded from the final return.

Any ideas?

**Update**

Sort of a half-hashed idea :

```
items_table = Arel::Table.new(scope)
unstarted_conversations = scope.select{|a| a.title == "Conversation" && a.replies.count > 0}.map(&:id)
scope.where(items_table[:id].not_in unstarted_conversations)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something called ***count cache***, basically what it does is add a field to the table and store in that field the total of "associates" of the specified type and is automatically updated.

Checkout this old screen/ascii cast: http://railscasts.com/episodes/23-counter-cache-column?view=asciicast

Here is something newer: http://hiteshrawal.blogspot.com/2011/12/rails-counter-cache.html

In your case would be as follow:

```
# migration
class AddCounterCacheToTopìc < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    add_column :topics, :replies_count, :integer, :default => 0
  end

  def self.down
    remove_column :topics, :replies_count
  end
end

# model
class Replay < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :topic, :counter_cache => true
end
```

Hope it help you.